# Como puedo hacer para que un length de una lista en haskell no me cuente los repetidos?

Tags: haskell

Necesito resolver un problema en `haskell` donde me pide que la funcion (llamemosle func1) reciba una lista y un precio maximo (la cual esta relacionada con los elementos de la lista), y cuente los elementos que no se repitan..
La lista que recibe es ['A','B','C','C','B','D','D'].
Ya he creado la funcion que me pasa los valores de la lista en numeros

```
func5(x) 
     | x == 'A' = 111
     | x == 'B' = 222
     | x == 'C' = 333
     | x == 'D' = 444
     | otherwise = 0

func6(l) = map func5(l)
```

lo que me pide es que muestre otra lista con los valores que no sean superiores al valor recibido por parámetro (por ejemplo: 350) y me cuente cuantos valores quedaron dentro de la lista. ( en este ejemplo serian solo 3) pero no se me ocurre como resolverlo

¿Alguien me ayudaría a resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es un poco farragosa de entender. Te recomiendo que sigas el estilo haskell para escribir código y que sigas las documentación de módulos como `Data.List` donde tienes funciones para operar con listas.

Por ejemplo, en haskell no se ponen parántesis para invocar una función como se hace en otros lenguajes:

```
func5 x 
     | x == 'A' = 111
     | x == 'B' = 222
     | x == 'C' = 333
     | x == 'D' = 444
     | otherwise = 0

func6 xs = map func5 xs
```

Por otro lado, siempre es recomendable añadir la *signatura* de las funciones para comprender mejor qué tipos de datos usa.

Así, con todo, lo que creo que estás pidiendo se resumen en que quieres *"contar cuántos elementos sin repetición hay en un lista que cumplan una condición (también conocido por predicado)"*.

Vayamos por partes, tenemos que combinar tres funciones:

1. el `nub` de `Data.List` para eliminar duplicados
2. `filter` para aplicar una condición
3. `length` para contar elementos

Y quedaría así:

```
import Data.List (nub)

count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
count f xs = (length . filter f . nub) xs
```

Comment: gracias por responder!
Mi problema es un tanto mas sencillo quiero suponer.. No hemos visto en la uni nada de lo que me has mostrado.. Por eso quiero suponer que debe haber una forma mas sencilla de resolverlo, he ahi mi problema.. No encuentro como hacerlo

Comment: Como comprenderás, no podemos suponer qué sabes o no sabes. Y tampoco te creas que hay otra *"forma más sencilla"*, porque éste era posiblemente el código más sencillo para resolver tu pregunta. No hay atajos, vas a tener que aprender.